# Does it make sense to wrap jQuery code in `document.ready()` inside your Angular 2 components functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, document-ready

I simply want to be sure that if the Angular component code is running. It means at that moment the `DOM` should be ready.
Example:: TypeScript

```
export class SomeComponent{
   constructor(){
     $('body').do();
   }
}
```

OR

```
export class SomeComponent{
   constructor(){
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('body').do();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use jQuery inside your angular2 app.

Comment: Is this about Angularjs or Angular2. Please fix the tags.

Comment: @RubyRacer that is a completely inaccurate statement. Of course `ready` will occur but not necessarily with proper sequencing for what OP needs within angular context since angular doesn't start compiling DOM until then either

Comment: angular code won't start running until after document ready would already have fired, so, no, this is senseless.

Comment: @RubyRacer that is completely not true. Angular can't prevent jQuery ready

Comment: Well, I've spent a few moments looking it up. It appears that my misconception is due to the fact that jQuery doc ready is indeed run before angular, but you can't use any jQuery outside the app to control it elements in it. I've erased my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code to `ngAfterViewInit()` of the root component `AppComponent`. When this lifecycle methos is called, you can be sure the DOM is ready. The `document.ready` event will have been sent way before this lifecycle method is called.

See also https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html

Comment: So because people think using jQuery with Angular is not a good idea, this question must not be answered? If you downvote you surely know better. How about adding a better answer?

Comment: I downoted this not because the question doesn't deserve an answer, but because this answer does not correctly answer the question asked. (View init for a given component has nothing to do with DOM ready.)

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks a lot for the feedback! You are right, the answer is not directly about DOM ready but as mentioned in the question he wants to execute code when the DOM is ready and I think using a lifecycle callback is close enough. I'll update my question though because this only makes sense in the root component.

Comment: I am not a veteran, but I think having each of the `ngAfterViewInit` in their components is better, not just the root component. Even after the root component is ready another component can create a new element on the DOM so the new element will probably not be accessible at the `afterViewInit` of the root component.

Comment: @SeyiAdekoya I would say that depends on the requirements. The initial view should be ready when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called. The child components are part of the view of the root component, they have to be ready as well for the root component to be ready. Dynamic parts like components added/removed because of route changes can change any time of course. But `document.ready` also doesn't cover that.